# How was Matisyahu's murder justified

Tags: chanuka, avodah-zarah, murder

According to sforim chitsoynim, Matisyahu murdered an unarmed villager in Modin. I believe this tale is repeated in Rabbinic sources, perhaps the Medrash, because I was taught it in Yeshiva. My question is what right Matisyahu had to murder the villager in cold blood. Even if he was chayav miso, wouldn't you need a full besdin to judge dinei nefashos?

Comment: The villager was not innocent. He was offering a sacrifice to an idol, in a blatant act of _avodah zarah_. The penalty is death. So Matisyahu struck him down. Simple as that.

Comment: @ezra "wouldn't you need a full besdin to judge dinei nefashos?"

Comment: I Macabees (2:26) compares the actions of Mattityahu to those of Pinhas who killed Zimri (Numbers 25:7). For a discussion of the actions of Pinhas in light of halakha, see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80405/8775). Notably, although it appears that according to the Talmud, the actions in question likely weren't included in the cases under the rubric of Pinhas's extrajudicial killings, they may well be included in other halakhic categories of extrajudicial killing (see the link).

Comment: @DoubleAA It's a question of "avid inish dina l'nafsheh" versus "lo avid inish dina l'nafsheh"; there's a machlokes in Bava Kamma 28 about it, although there's no maskanah. If I remember correctly, though, the Tur and Shulchan Aruch discuss and rule that it is permissable to take the law into your own hands, avid inish dina l'nafsheh.

Comment: @ezra so you agree it's not as simple as what you said

Comment: @DoubleAA Almost nothing in Yiddishkeit is simple. :) But anyway, bli neder I'll find the place in the Tur I'm talking about; I just reviewed it not too long ago.

Comment: @ezra probably choshen mishpat 2 or 4 or so iinm